# IPTables how to nat 10.8.a.b to 10.0.a.b?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, iptables

## The problem -- Translate 10.8.a.b to 10.0.a.b ?

I have a VPN setup to a bastion host. I'm attempting to map `10.8.0.0/17` into `10.0.0.0/17` so that the IP address `10.8.1.1` gets mapped to `10.0.1.1` in my local network.

I imagine the culprit of this problem is

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.8.0.0/17 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.0-10.0.127.255
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
####
# This allows you to DNAT connections in a round-robin way over a given range of destination addresses.
# --to-destination ipaddr-ipaddr
#     Address range to round-robin over.
```

```
# What I Want:
#    10.8.0.1 -> 10.0.0.253 -> 10.0.0.1
# What I Get:
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), snapshot length 262144 bytes
04:41:15.934726 IP 10.8.255.1 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 93, seq 1, length 64

listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
05:50:27.228399 IP 10.0.0.253 > 10.0.52.24: ICMP echo request, id 93, seq 1, length 64
                                ^^^^^^^^^^
                              Wrong IP Address!!!
```

How do I write the (first 17 bit/last 15 bits) of the destination into a new destination.
A more clear example of what I'm aiming to achieve is **10.8.0.100** in the VPN correlates to **10.0.0.100** in my LAN network.

Note: This is my first time setting up routing between two networks, if there's any obvious mistakes or inconsistency with normal conventions please address it, I'm still learning.
IPTables how to nat 10.8.a.b to 10.0.a.b?

## Networks

## LAN (10.0.0.0/16)

| network | VPN IP |
| --- | --- |
| **10.0.0.1** | ISP Gateway |
| **10.0.0.253** | Home OpenVPN Gateway (**10.8.255.2**) |

## VPN (10.8.0.0/16)

| network | VPN IP |
| --- | --- |
| **10.8.0.0/16** | Reserved Clients (Start at **10.8.128.1**) |
| **10.8.0.0/17** | IP Forward NAT **10.8.0.0/17 -> 10.0.0.0/17 via 10.8.255.2** |
| **10.8.255.1** | Cloud Server Gateway |
| **10.8.255.2** | Home OpenVPN Gateway (LAN: **10.0.0.253**) |

#### VPN Routes

| network | gateway | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **10.8.0.0/16** | **10.8.255.1** | Entire network |
| **10.8.0.0/17** | **10.8.255.2** | all IP address should translate the last 15 bits onto the destination (**10.8.0.100 -> 10.0.0.100**) |

## IPTables

```
root@gwhome# iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
root@gwhome# iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
root@gwhome# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
root@gwhome# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.8.0.0/17 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.0-10.0.127.255
```

**This machine is not the network gateway**, so I've seen some people mention the need for `SNAT`, but I think the need for this should be alleviated by `MASQUERADE`. A confirmation on this would be appreciated.

### ping 10.8.0.1 (LAN: 10.0.0.1)

```
root@cloud-server# ping 10.8.0.1 -c 3
PING 10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.8.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2078ms
```

### tun0 sniff

```
root@gwhome# tcpdump -i tun0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), snapshot length 262144 bytes
04:41:15.934726 IP 10.8.255.1 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 89, seq 1, length 64
04:41:16.989078 IP 10.8.255.1 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 89, seq 2, length 64
04:41:18.013008 IP 10.8.255.1 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 89, seq 3, length 64
^C
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

### eth0 sniff

```
root@gwhome# tcpdump -i eth0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
05:50:27.228399 IP 10.0.0.253 > 10.0.52.24: ICMP echo request, id 93, seq 1, length 64
05:50:28.234007 IP 10.0.0.253 > 10.0.52.24: ICMP echo request, id 93, seq 2, length 64
05:50:29.257588 IP 10.0.0.253 > 10.0.52.24: ICMP echo request, id 93, seq 3, length 64
^C
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: Although this is easy to achieve in iptables, why *do* you want to perform this kind of NAT in the first place, instead of directly routing 10.0.0.0/16 via the VPN gateway?

Comment: @user1686 Thank you for your time, My home network is on 10.0.0.0/16, and my office also uses 10.0.0.0/16, this VPN is to enter my home network from my office, so I'll need to have the address translated to avoid overlapping IP addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DNAT` target won't work here; it translates everything to *one* host or to a randomly selected host from the specified range. (Basically it is meant to be used when matching *one* destination host, i.e. `-d foo/32`.)

For prefix translation you'd be looking for the `NETMAP` target:

- iptables:
  `-d 10.8.0.0/16 -j NETMAP --to 10.0.0.0/16`
- nftables (new):
  `ip daddr 10.8.0.0/16 dnat ip prefix to ip daddr map { 10.8.0.0/16 : 10.0.0.0/16 }`
- nftables (all versions):
  `ip daddr 10.8.0.0/16 dnat to ip addr & 0.0.255.255 | 10.8.0.0`

(Other than that, `NETMAP` is still a form of DNAT and uses the same iptables NAT/conntrack infrastructure as `DNAT` does.)

> This machine is not the network gateway, so I've seen some people mention the need for SNAT, but I think the need for this should be alleviated by MASQUERADE. A confirmation on this would be appreciated.

Yes, `MASQUERADE` is also SNAT, except it automatically chooses the new source address from the outbound interface while the `SNAT` target requires it to be specified manually.

Even if you cannot configure routes for the VPN on your LAN gateway, you can still (partially) avoid the need for SNAT by configuring the same route directly on each host (e.g. using `route -p add` on Windows, or DHCP option 121). This isn't something you can do on *all* devices, but may be enough if you only want to access a PC or a server.

Answer (score 5):

The IPTables target you want is [`NETMAP`](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDF):

> This target allows you to statically map a whole network of addresses onto another network of addresses. It can only be used from rules in the nat table.
>
> **--to** *address*[/*mask*]
>     Network address to map to. The resulting address will be constructed in the following way: All 'one' bits in the mask are filled in from the new `address'. All bits that are zero in the mask are filled in from the original address.
> IPv6 support available since Linux kernels >= 3.7.

Also keep in mind that your local hosts (in *10.0.0.0/17*) MUST direct their response traffic to the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Another workable solution is to go through the **one-time pain of renumbering** your home network to something more unique.

Instead of picking the common networks, renumber with a block out of 172.16.0.0/12 which goes up to 172.31.255.255.

This may be as little as re-configuring your router's LAN port and DHCP scope, and updating any device with a static DHCP reservation or static local IP config.  You may have to reconfigure network printers or cameras too.

A good candidate is 172.27.0.0 /16 or a smaller netblock if you don't need that many IPs.

192.168.(something between 100 and 254) /24 would be useful too.  The blocks in 192.168.0 and 1 and 10 tend to be over-used.

Other uncommon RFC1918 blocks might include subnets from 198.18.0.0/15  There's a full list at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#IPv4 though your results might vary with some of the specialty networks.

Choose wisely and you'll never have to do this again.

Comment: I realise this doesn't answer the question as posted, but does resolve the underlying issue of conflicting network blocks while also decreasing complexity.  Adding NAT never simplifies things and should be a last resort.

Comment: Good idea, though `172.16/12` is also a minefield. Used in some corporate networks and many(!) virtualization/containerization solutions. IMHO, good old `192.168/16` is the way to go for home networks.

Comment: @DanielB fair call - though 192.168.200-through-250.x  would be less-used in my guess rather than the 192.168.0 or 1 or 10 or 20 or 100 ranges.